# how to configure nginx reverse proxy for tomcat servers?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat

Well, I have been given the task of "modernizing" an application of the Pleistocene and I can't make this work. Let me explain:

I have a series of tomcat servers, each with the following structure:

```
(partner1 - tomcatServer1)
http://myServerIp1:8080/ ->tomcat index
http://myServerIp1:8080/webapp1 ->webapp1(main)
http://myServerIp1:8080/webapp2 ->webapp2
(partner2 - tomcatServer2)
http://myServerIp2:8080/ ->tomcat index
http://myServerIp2:8080/webapp1 ->webapp1(main)
http://myServerIp2:8080/webapp2 ->webapp2
http://myServerIp2:8080/webapp3 ->webapp3
```

As you can see, at first I find several very visible problems.

1. To begin with, they use a public ip, which complicates the task of
   finding an ssl certificate (but this will be addressed later).
2. Each server contains several applications.

My initial idea to "modernize" the application was to use a domain and through a dedicated nginx server, make a reverse proxy that uses the following structure

```
(partner1 - tomcatServer1)
http://partner1.myDomain.com/ ->webapp1(main)
http://partner1.myDomain.com/webapp2 ->webapp2
(partner2 - tomcatServer2)
http://partner2.myDomain.com/ ->webapp1(main)
http://partner2.myDomain.com/webapp2 ->webapp2
http://partner2.myDomain.com/webapp3 ->webapp3
```

And once this was achieved I would start fighting with the use of ssl. I say this, and I make special mention to it, because I don't want to start with ssl without first checking that it works without it, because I can't even make a good proxy_pass to the tomcat index since it only loads the text without images. If I made a redirect there would be no problems, but the idea is that the client stops using an ip and finally has a serious domain

Of course, not only have I tried with the tomcat index, before I had started to try directly with the webapp1 and found that it gave no error... but it showed absolutely nothing. Seeing this has been when I went to look at the index and I realized that it did not load well either.

At first I thought that the problem could be solved by creating a virtualhost in tomcat for each webapp because I thought that the problem was a brute and make a direct proxy_pass to http://myServerIp1:8080/webapp1/, but once configured the virtual host of tomcat, the result was the same, a completely white page.

I need help, and I think the best way to start is to start from the beginning. Let's see if you can help me by making the tomcat index load correctly

For this, I leave the tomcat configuration for now without virtualhosts and this would be the nginx configuration for the tomcat index at http://partner1.myDomain.com/ (later, if this loads well I start testing with the applications)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name partner1.myDomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://myServerIp1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is a slight modification of the default nginx file in debian.
If I look at the development tools of the browser, I can see that it has problems with the loading of elements such as "tomcat.css, favicon.ico...".

Comment: Please share a snippet of the HTML code that refers to a resource that it doesn't load, when you load the HTML via nginx. For example `<link>` tag for the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a situation similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/998655/530633). Tomcat does not know it is being proxied and the generated absolute URLs start with `http://myServerIp:8080`.

You need to add a [RemoteIpValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve) to you `<Host>`:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" />
```

and set `requestAttributesEnabled=true` on your `AccessLogValve` (so the logs contain the real IPs).

NGINX will need to send to Tomcat the `Host`, `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers:

```
proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

(the `X-Real-IP` header is already contained in `X-Forwarded-For`).

After you modify the configuration the applications running on Tomcat will behave as if Tomcat was running on `partner1.example.com:80`. Moreover, when you switch to `HTTPS`, Tomcat will know that the request came from a secure channel and will generate `https://` links.

**Edit:** In your updated configuration you change the absolute path of the proxied pages from `/myWebapp/` to `/`. I'll advise against it: Tomcat sets the cookie path for `JSESSIONID` to the context path `/myWebapp/` so the web browser never sends the cookie back. Use a configuration like this instead:

```
    location = / {
        return 301 http://partner1.example.com/myWebapp/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myServerIp.8080;
        include    nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }
```

which redirects clients from `/` to `/myWebapp/`, but otherwise keeps the paths intact.

Note: `myDomain.com` is a valid domain belonging to someone, therefore it is better to use the [domains reserved for documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) in questions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to get there without touching tomcat, in fact I managed to see the application like this:
http://myServerIp.8080/myWebapp/ -->
http://partner1.myDomain.com/

But then I ran into another problem.
Just after starting the application the jsessionid is not maintained and is updated in each request. I have tried solutions like:
[Add samesite to cookies using Nginx as reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/849888/add-samesite-to-cookies-using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy)
[Using nginx as a reverse proxy for tomcat results in new jsessionids for every ssl request](https://serverfault.com/questions/426261/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat-results-in-new-jsessionids-for-every-s)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542525/nginx-how-to-take-value-from-header-and-set-it-into-cookie
and now I have tried modifying tomcat as you indicate. However the Jsessionid keeps changing, I manage to enter the application, but when I make that request it changes again and when I enter the application everything fails and it presents me as unauthorized.

This would be my configuration

```
---------------
-----nginx.conf
---------------
user                 www-data;
pid                  /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset              utf-8;
    sendfile             on;
    tcp_nopush           on;
    tcp_nodelay          on;
    server_tokens        off;
    log_not_found        off;
    types_hash_max_size  2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include              mime.types;
    default_type         application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log           /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log            /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # Load configs
    include              /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include              /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

---------------
-----General
---------------


# favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
}

# robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
}

# gzip
gzip            on;
gzip_vary       on;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

---------------
-----Proxy
---------------


proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host              $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

# Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;


---------------
-----webapp
---------------


server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name partner1.myDomain.com;

    # logging
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/partner1.myDomain.com.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/partner1.myDomain.com.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myServerIp.8080/myWebapp/;
        include    nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, you should [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1050569/edit) your question and add this data. Not everyone will read other people answers. I updated my answer to address your new questions.